# Is it possible to inject a service inside another service and vice versa at the same time?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, ecmascript-6, ionic2

I have a real scenario in a real project where I need 2 services to access the properties and/or methods of each other. I'm not an Angular expert so is it possible?

I have tried and it fails. Here's my attempt:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FirstService } from './first.service';
import { SecondService } from './second.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>Hello world!</h1>',
  providers: [FirstService, SecondService]
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(public firstService: FirstService, public secondService: SecondService) {
    console.log(firstService.foo);
    console.log(secondService.bar);
  }

}
```

first.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SecondService } from './second.service';

@Injectable()
export class FirstService {

  foo: string = 'abc';

  constructor(public secondService: SecondService) {
    this.foo = this.foo + this.secondService.bar;
  }

}
```

second.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FirstService } from './first.service';

@Injectable()
export class SecondService {

  bar: string = 'xyz';

  constructor(public firstService: FirstService) {
    this.bar = this.bar + this.firstService.foo;
  }

}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/PQ7Uw1WHpvzPRf6yyLFd?p=preview

Just injecting the second service into the first service works fine but as soon as I inject the first service into the second service it fails and throws errors to the console.

So what is wrong?

A working solution should print the following to the console log:

```
abcxyz
xyzabc
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularJS does not allow injection of circular dependencies.

Miško Hevery, one of the authors of AngularJS, recommends finding the common elements:

```
+---------+      +---------+
|    A    |<-----|  B      |
|         |      |  |  +-+ |
|         |      |  +->|C| |
|         |------+---->| | |
|         |      |     +-+ |
+---------+      +---------+
```

And extracting it to a third service:

```
                         +---------+
+---------+              |    B    |
|    A    |<-------------|         |
|         |              |         |
|         |    +---+     |         |
|         |--->| C |<----|         |
|         |    +---+     +---------+
+---------+
```

For more information, see [Circular Dependency in constructors and Dependency Injection](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/) by **Miško Hevery**.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm not an Angular expert so is it possible

No. Circular dependencies are not resolved by angular's DI.

Also even systems that do support it, quite commonly are inconsistent e.g. commonjs https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_cycles will give you an empty object for a while.

## Solution

Consider combining the two services into *one*. You can still move certain stuff (e.g. simple functions etc) out from the combined service if it becomes too much.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the solution proposed by basarat. Another workaround would be to initialize the instances outside DI and provide them as value like

One service needs to be modified to be able to create an instance without providing the other service as dependency:

```
@Injectable()
export class FirstService {

  foo: string = 'abc';
  secondService: SecondService

  constructor() {
    //this.foo = this.foo + this.secondService.bar;
  }

  init(secondService:SecondService) {
    this.foo = this.foo + secondService.bar;
  }
}
```

Then create the instances imperatively and provide them as value

```
let firstService = new FirstService();
let secondService = new SecondService(firstService);

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>Hello world!</h1>',
  providers: [
    provide(FirstService, {useFactory: () => {
      firstService.init(secondService);
      return firstService;
  }}), provide(SecondService, {useValue: secondService})]
})
...
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/PmpLuxi3gIoGXkOL11KQ?p=preview)

Comment: is `circular dependencies` exist in angular2 ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. "circular dependencies" work with classes but DI can't instantiate classes that have circular dependencies.